# Can't get item from preferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've got a preferences.xml stored in my res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <Preference android:key="units_length" android:title="imperial"></Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is how the onCreate method looks like in my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.results);

// Get preferences
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);

// Fetch the text view
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

// Set new text
text.setText(preferences.getString("units_length", "nothing"));

}
```

My application just says "nothing". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well.. I want it to fetch units_length from the preferences, so that it says "imperial". I thought that was pretty obvious from my question.

Comment: Then you should set your default value to "imperial" instead of "nothing".

Comment: What? I don't think you should comment on topics you don't understand.

Comment: Default value is returned when you're trying to access a preference that doesn't exist. You did not create your preference, means you did not call putString("units_length","imperial"), so the simplest way for you is to set your preference's default value to "imperial".

Comment: I did create my preference, look in the xml file above.

Comment: Preference is a key-value pair, what you're trying to get is value, and android:title does not define value. Value can be defined via calling the putString(key, value), or you can define the android:defaultValue and set it to whatever value you want. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Half-answering questions make you look like a smart ass. You could have told me in your previous comments that defaultValue was missing, sigh.. If you had looked in the answer below, you would have seen that I have actually already tried that, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `android:defaultValue` attribute in your preference xml definition to whatever appropriate. It seems that property have never been initialized.

Comment: try obtaining `SharedPreferences` object by calling `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`

Comment: I've tested the code and it works but only when using `EditTextPreference`, I didn't realize it could be different when using just simple `Preference`, in that case I think it would be the best to initialize your preference manually or use default value in `get*()` methods

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to go on. I appreciate your time.